# bulk Update post_meta with default values

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a site which has 1000+ posts,  after recently adding a new custom field ( with ACF ) obviously that post_meta data will not excist until I have gone through every single post and updated it with a value.

So ive found this code :

```
function my_acf_load_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    $value = get_the_title(); 
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=amazon_keywords', 'my_acf_load_value', 10, 3);
```

Which sets the default value of the field to the wp-title,  so when I goto a post the post title is already entered in the custom field ready for me to save.

With that in mind,  is there anyway I can do this without having to go into every single post and re-save it ? Like a bulk update ?  I tried to bulk update from the post listings screen but it doesnt seem to execute the saving of custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new bulk action for posts with this code :

```
$postType = "post";


add_filter("bulk_actions-edit-" . $postType, function ($actions) {

    $actions["specialSave"] = "Special save";

    return $actions;

}, 20);


add_filter("handle_bulk_actions-edit-" . $postType, function ($sendback, $doaction, $post_ids) {

    if ("specialSave" !== $doaction) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($post_ids as $idPost) {

        // action to do for each selected post



    }

    return $sendback;


}, 10, 3);
```

is a simple save is not enough to set the value, you can use this code to set the value directly for each selected post.