# Custom bulk page permissions

Tags: bulk

I don't know if I am phrasing this question right, but having a hard time finding an answer. What I want to do is open up my posts or pages dashboard and be able to bulk edit pages' permissions. So I would like to add a dropdown to the bulk edit area that allows me to select a user role for that page. Currently, I have to add the permissons by editing the page and selecting the roles for permissions. The site is huge so this would take me way too long. Anyone have any ideas? thank you.

Comment: What do you use to edit permission of a page now ? a selfmade plugin ?

Comment: I am using User Role Editor. It puts an option on each page and post to set permissions, but it just seems like a pain to go into each page to do that.

Comment: I dont see that with User Role Editor, are you sure it's not another plugin ? when you have found how to code the modification, you can add a bulk action with that : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290621/bulk-update-post-meta-with-default-values/290626#290626